Spring Security OAuth2 custom login page, start auth flow automatically
In my spring application, when i don't configure a custom loginPage, Spring starts the authentication flow whenever i hit a protected route, and also redirects to that route when the authentication flow is finished, which is what i want.
However, when for example there is an error (e.g. access_denied), Spring redirects to the default /login?error page. This is the page i want to customize.
So i tried to set a custom loginPage, which also works, but now, when i hit a protected route, i get redirected to that loginPage, but that is not what i want. Instead i still want Spring to automatically start the authentication flow. Is this possible?
Here is my configuration:
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .userInfoEndpoint(
                userInfo -> userInfo.userService(this.oauth2UserService()))
        ).logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout"));
    return http.build();
  }

